# R S4 signature: list-element

Tags: r, oop, r-s4

Is it possible in R to choose a S4 method based on the values a list has?

```
setGeneric(name = "mwe_fun"
           , def = function(arg1) standardGeneric( "mwe_fun" ) )
setMethod(
    f = "mwe_fun"
    ,signature = c("list_characterInside"),
    function(arg1){
        return("I am a character list")
    })
setMethod(
    f = "mwe_fun"
    ,signature = c("list_numericInside"),
    function(arg1){
        return("I am a numeric list")
    })


## example:
mwe_fun(list("a"=c(1,2,3), "b"=c(2,3,4))) 
# > "I am a numeric list"

mwe_fun(list("a"="asdjh", "b"="alkfjasfd")) 
# > "I am a character list"


## maybe even:

mwe_fun(list("a"=c(1,2,3), "b"=c(2,3,4))) 
# > "I am a NAMED numeric list"
mwe_fun(list(c(1,2,3), c(2,3,4))) 
# > "I am a UNNAMED numeric list"
```

Or do I have to make something like

```
setGeneric(name = "mwe_fun"
           , def = function(arg1) standardGeneric( "mwe_fun" ) )
setMethod(
    f = "mwe_fun"
    ,signature = c("list"),
    function(arg1){
        if( all(lapply(a, typeof) == "double")) return("I am a numeric list")
        if( all(lapply(a, typeof) == "character")) return("I am a character list")
    })
```

"It looks like my post is mostly code", but I think i made my point quite clearly - please let me know if it is not!

Comment: Your second option is the way to go. You can check inside the method what to do depending on the input object.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to skin this particular cat. As you have realised, you can't use the ordinary generic mechanism, since the class of all of these objects is simply `list`.

One neat solution is to define your own generic, but one level down. If this code is intended for a package, you don't even need to export that generic. For example:

```
setGeneric(name = ".mwe_fun",
  def = function(list,listExample) standardGeneric( "mwe_fun" ),
  signature=c("listExample") ## we don't include "list" in the signature
)
mwe_fun <- function(list){
  .mwe_fun(list,list[[1]])
}
```

Now you can write methods for `.mwe_fun` for signature `listExample="numeric"` and so on.

The way I have written it, the methods are chosen based on the class of the first element of the list. You might want to do things differently (perhaps checking that all elements have the same class and throwing an error if not). This can be done inside `mwe_fun`, before `.mwe_fun` is called.

In a package, you only need to export `mwe_fun`. `.mwe_fun` can reside entirely in the package namespace and doesn't need to be exported unless another package defines methods for it.

Comment: really neat idea!
I have been going the way nicola affirmed but nevertheless the next time it might be a great option!

Comment: Another alternative might be to use `do.call` as a wrapper, and rely on the fact that you can use `...` as a signature (see the help for `dotsMethods`)